# How do I properly upgrade SVN on MAC?

Tags: macos, svn

I'm starting on a new team who are all on PCs using `TortoiseSVN` with `SVN version 1.9.2`. I'm on a Mac OSX (El Capitan) using the Versionsapp. When I check `svn --version` in terminal i get `1.7.10`.

When I try any svn command such as `svn update` I get

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
'/Users/dpowell/Desktop/sites/site.org.new' (format 31).
You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see
  http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change
```

I've gone to the site and downloaded the python script but don't know it will do anything to help (i.e. I don't know how to use it). I've also downloaded the `1.9` package and tried installing `svn` that way.

I'm not sure what path to take to solve this issue

Answer (score 9):

The Python script you downloaded from there was to downgrade your SVN version - you need to upgrade your SVN version. I recommend going the homebrew route - it will save you lots of pain in upgrading / installing OSX packages in the future.

Follow the instructions here: http://brew.sh/

(copy that line into a terminal an press ENTER, then follow the prompts)

Then, when homebrew is installed, so update SVN, just do `brew install svn`.

Comment: I just did this (no errors) and checked `svn --version` and it's still `1.7.10`

Comment: What is the output when you type `which svn`? How did you install SVN originally?

Comment: `which svn` outputs `/usr/bin/svn`. I don't remember how I installed it originally, it's been quite a while since then. I do have Versionsapp installed but that was very recent.

Comment: do I need to reset or restart anything?

Comment: Ok, `/usr/bin/svn` is where svn gets installed NOT through homebrew. So what you want to do is make sure you have a file `/usr/local/bin/svn`. If you do `/usr/local/bin/svn --version` you should get version 1.9.3. If that is the case, then you want to do `sudo rm /usr/bin/svn`, then `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/svn /usr/lib/svn`. Then do `svn --version` and you should be all set.

Comment: This tells me that the operation is not permitted when trying the last command

Comment: `svn --version` is not permitted?

Comment: @mprat I think he means `sudo rm /usr/bin/svn`

Comment: It does say operation _operation not permitted_ to `sudo rm /usr/bin/svn`

Comment: Is this a laptop administered by someone else? You can try updating the version you currently have (`svn upgrade`), which might not require root permissions. If that is also not allowed, you might have to be stuck with doing `/usr/local/bin/svn --version` and typing the full path all the time.

Comment: Took hours of online searching just to find "brew install svn".  Fixed everything.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. In Terminal, type "svn --version" to find out what version you currently have
> 2. Go to http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx and download the latest client for OS X and install it. This will install the new svn into /opt/subversion/bin
> 3. Got to your terminal and check your $PATH by typing "echo $PATH". If you don't see /opt/subversion/bin in there, make sure you add it by typing export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH. If it DOES exist and appears AFTER /usr/bin, then you may need to remove an older copy of svn that came installed on OS X. To do so, go to /usr/bin and remove all files starting with svn. This isn't an exact science but it should do the trick.
>      For me  export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH worked as it was installed in /opt/subversion/bin
> 4. Make sure you reload your .profile first by typing
>      . ./.profile*
> 5. Type "svn --version". You should see that you have the newest version installed!

Answer (score 4):

`brew upgrade subversion`

Others solutions require you to register an Account?? forget them.

Comment: This works only if subversion was installed by brew , otherwise it will show Error: subversion not installed .

Comment: @AnoopD, so you install it, don't upgrade it.

Comment: Mac comes preinstalled with older versions of subversion . I updated it to the current stable following the link here by replacing the version in `curl` command https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/

Comment: as @mprat points out in Catalina you need to install subversion with  `brew install svn`